# javascript lookback regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to replace all alphabets in the string which are not preceded by `_` by numeric `1`.

So

```
jj*_sin(jj)+_cos(hh)
```

should be

```
1*_sin(1)+_cos(1)
```

How to achieve it with regex lookbacks or any other method.

Comment: Write a parser. Don't use regex (which may solve your problem at first, but it will fail on slightly more complex instances).

Answer (score 4):

Use a negative lookahead assertion like below.

```
(?!_)\b[a-z]+
```

Then replace the matched characters by `1`

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rF9jP6/6)

```
> "jj*_sin(jj)+_cos(hh)".replace(/(?!_)\b[a-z]+/g, "1")
'1*_sin(1)+_cos(1)'
```

**OR**

```js
var str = "jj*_sin(jj)+_cos(hh)";
snippet.log("Before: " + str);
str = str.replace(/(^|[^_])\b[a-z]+/g, "$11");
snippet.log("After:  " + str);
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

`\b` word boundary is an important thing in the above regex which matches between a word character and a non-word character. `(^|[^_])` captures the start of a line or a character not of underscore. `\b` is important here, because without `\b`, it would match the strings like this `9foo`. `\b` ensures that the alphabets are preceded by a  non-word character or starting anchor. `[a-z]+` matches one or more lowercase alphabets. So by replacing all the matched characters with the characters inside group index 1 plus a digit `1` will will give you the desired output.

Comment: That's a better option. How 'bout adding a Stack Snippet to keep the demo on-site (not that *also* linking to regex101's excellent explanation isn't great).

Comment: Feel free to grab the one from my answer and change it, just as a leg-up on Stack Snippets. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You *can* do this with `String#replace` and a regex, but as [nhahtdh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1400768/nhahtdh) points out [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27677946/javascript-lookback-regex/27678003#comment43770252_27677946), it's likely to only get you so far. You'll probably be better off building a parser, possibly using Jison or any of serveral other parser generators.

The way you do it is by using a capture group and a callback function:

```js
var str = "jj*_sin(jj)+_cos(hh)";
snippet.log("Before: " + str);
str = str.replace(/(_?)([a-zA-Z]+)/g, function(m, c0, c1) {
  return c0 === "_" ? m : c0 + "1";
});
snippet.log("After:  " + str);
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

1*_sin(1)+_cos(1)

```js
var str = "jj*_sin(jj)+_cos(hh)";
snippet.log("Before: " + str);
str = str.replace(/(_?)([a-zA-Z]+)/g, function(m, c0, c1) {
  return c0 === "_" ? m : c0 + "1";
});
snippet.log("After:  " + str);
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. A little explanation would be nice.